# Prevent changing window height

Tags: android, android-window

When showing the keyboard, the window height decreases and my layout is displayed incorrectly because of this.

[image]

UPD.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:translationZ="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/horizon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconNoLoading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:translationZ="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/errorMessage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_no_loading" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/errorMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/horizon"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRetry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:elevation="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/errorMessage" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/horizon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I added the markup code, but this is unlikely to help, the point is that the android resizes the window when the keyboard appears, and I can’t prevent you from doing this.

I tried to specify `windowSoftInputMode` parameter but it doesn't help, how can I fix it?

Comment: Hello wpbloger. It would help a lot, if you provided the code (in this case, especially your XML).

Comment: Are you open to using a relativelayout instead of a coordinatorlayout

Comment: @fireball.1 If the problem cannot be solved otherwise, then yes, but why is coordinatorlayout so bad?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, but now I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and the window now does not shrink when the keyboard appears and does not break the layout, although I did the same before and it did not work ...